# Qt configure warning No backend for low level audio found

Tags: c++, qt, configure

I am setting up a cross-compile environment for Raspberry Pi (compiling on AlmaLinux 9). When I run the Qt configure program on AlmaLinux it succeeds but I get error:

```
WARNING: No backend for low level audio found.
```

What does this warning mean? What is missing, and is the problem on the Raspberry or the AlmaLinux computer? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to search a directory files for a string:

```
grep -r "No backend for low level audio found." ../qt-everywhere-src-6.5.1/
```

and the response will be:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-6.5.1/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/configure.cmake:    MESSAGE "No backend for low level audio found."
```

if you look inside **qt-everywhere-src-6.5.1/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/configure.cmake**

you see:

```
qt_configure_add_report_entry(
    TYPE WARNING
    MESSAGE "No backend for low level audio found."
    CONDITION NOT QT_FEATURE_alsa AND NOT QT_FEATURE_pulseaudio AND NOT QT_FEATURE_mmrenderer AND NOT QT_FEATURE_coreaudio AND NOT QT_FEATURE_wmsdk AND NOT ANDROID AND NOT WASM
)
```

which means none of the mentioned libraries were found on your system.

running `sudo apt-get build-dep qt6-multimedia-dev` should reveal the dependancies, anything other than qt related libraries.